# Android colors theme

Tags: android, colors, themes

I want to make a few themes for my app that change a few colors. I've read about it but I'm confused... What are the advantages of using the color defined in the resources xml ?

Suppose that I have 1 or 2 textview and i want to change a couple of combinations of the background color and font color, how to do that ?

Comment: Styles and Themes in Android is similar to cascading stylesheets in web design. They allow you to separate the design from the content. What is the spesific point that make you feel confused? @Jackd

Comment: Thanks. Suppose, a simple case, I wanto to make a coulple of combinations of background color of a view and font color, How do i set up combinations and apply ?

Comment: Cos here, doesnt explain very much: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html